# Google compute/app engine to access VPN network

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a problem statement. All my apps are moved to google cloud. I have few less cost supportive solutions such as virtual services in my network. So moving these virtual environment to cloud is not much cost effective according to me, instead, if I connect my google cloud engine to my VPN, I can open the bridge to access the virtual environment. Is is possible to access my VPN from google cloud? I went through the docs https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/

It says about creating VPN in google cloud. Correct me if my understanding is wrong, pardon me if it is duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Google Compute Engine is different to Google App Engine. You mention both. Which are you trying to connect to via VPN?

For GCE, yes you can create a [site-to-site VPN](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/). You'll need a dedicated physical or virtual VPN gateway in your network and you can then connect it to a Google VPN Gateway in GCE. The two networks CIDR ranges cannot overlap.

Comment: I'll go with Compute engine. So you mean to say, I should create a VPN server in compute engine and do server-to-server VPN connectivity?

Comment: You'll have two VPN *gateways*, one in your on-premise network and one in GCE. Traffic flowing from one network to the other is routed over a VPN tunnel between the two gateways. Take a look at the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/#creating_a_vpn